# Download and commit gradle dependencies and plugins in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This is an excerpt from a *build.gradle* file for one of my modules. I'm using **android-studio-1.5.1** and **gradle 2.10**.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

I also have `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` in the *project level build.gradle* file.

I'm trying to gather all the associated jars into a directory which I can commit to my git repo. Something like:

```
task copyRuntimeLibs(type: Copy) {
    into "${projectDir}/libs"
    from configurations.compile
}
```

(This does not work)
Also, I'm not trying to download the sources or javadocs.

I need to be able to commit all dependencies so that the project can be shared on an intranet without internet access.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a plugin which will download all jars and poms. See the code [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-dependency-export/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/lazan/dependency/export/MavenDependencyExport.groovy#L46) to download all jars and all poms from a Gradle [Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html)

Note: There's a failing test [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-dependency-export/blob/master/src/test/groovy/com/lazan/dependency/export/MavenDependencyExportTest.groovy#L69) which shows that the parent pom's are not being downloaded. I've raised an issue [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2809) on Gradle's github.

I will likely improve the plugin to invoke the [Maven Model Builder APIs](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.2/maven-model-builder/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/building/ModelBuilder.html) to get the parent poms.

FYI - I've already integrated the ModelBuilder APIs successfully with Gradle (see [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-maven-transform/blob/master/plugin/src/main/groovy/com/lazan/maven/transform/MavenTransform.java#L138) and [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-maven-transform/blob/master/plugin/src/main/groovy/com/lazan/maven/transform/internal/ModelResolverImpl.java)) so shouldn't be too difficult.